# Codeigniter Product Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

I have a controller Products and DB table categories.

Products has index function which determines from what category should the products be loaded.

But the URL looks like this: `products/index/(category-name)`

And I want it to look like this: `products/(category-name)`

Could someone help me please? I would be very thankful.

NOTE: I do have RewriteEngine On

SOLUTION: `$route['^(en|sk)/products/(:any)'] = "/products/index/$1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this;

```
$route['products/(:any)'] = "products/index/$1";
```

That will work for you.

Comment: I doesn't. I still get the 404 page.

Comment: Then there is an issue with your controller format, what does it look like? Is the main function called Index?

Comment: I have public function index() 
But i forgot to mention that I'm using i18n library for languages. 
so my links look like this: localhost/(lang)/(controller) 

I'm not sure if that makes any difference

Comment: Try this then;  $route['products/(:any)'] = "lang/products/index/$1";   replace the lang with the language, just for testing.

Comment: Try using the first thing i sent you and disabling the language.